# Likert Scaled Item Response Rate: What if only 2% of my ppts chose "1"?

Tags: likert, confirmatory-factor

**Background**: I am examining the psychometric properties of a 6-item unidimensional measure in psychology. The items are rated on a 1-5 scale with strongly disagree <-> strong agree anchors. A scale score is computed by averaging across the items. Specifically, I am using confirmatory factor analysis to test the theorized factor structure (I will also be examining validity, reliability, etc.).

**Question**: given the above situation and that you believe ordinal data can be assumed to be continuous in *some* situations, is there a minimum percent of my cases that need to select a given answer option (e.g., "1: Strongly Disagree) in order to assume that my data is continuous? I.e., say only 2% of my cases indicate "1: Strongly Disagree" for item 1. Is this a problem? What about if only 2% of my cases indicate "1: Strongly Disagree" for the measure as a whole?

I have heard that there is a rough rule around 5%, but I have yet to find a citation for it. I.e., I have heard that if less than 5% of my cases indicate a response (e.g., "1: Strongly Disagree"), that A) I can no longer assume my data is continuous, and B) that I should combine that response with another (e.g., combine 1 with 2 to create a "Disagree" category).

What are you thoughts on this? Is there a common citation that I have been missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Likert scaled items are "continuous" is like assuming they are symmetrically distributed and bell-shaped. The conventions or rules of thumb around the proportions of respondents falling into each point of the scale are just that -- rules of thumb that are typically falsified by real data. While there is a multitude of psychometric literature on these issues, most of it is not recent as *psychometrics* has kind of fallen by the wayside in terms of active academic interest, grant funding, etc. This doesn't mean that the issues dealt with by this field have gone away, just that much of the active research has -- at least for now.

Norman Cliff's late 80s book *Analyzing Multivariate Data* is the single best reference I'm aware of to discuss these issues. In addition to dealing with assumptions of normality in analyzing Likert scales, he discusses deleterious "end effects" -- items where a large proportion of respondents fall at the upper or lower bounds of the scale -- and approaches to blunting them. These include using stronger adjectives to anchoring the scales -- words such as "Never," "Extremely," and so on -- as well as a preference for seven point over five point scales. He also covers approaches to decomposing halo effects where respondents have a bias towards using a constrained range of the scale. Regrettably, once "end" and "halo" effects are baked into your data, most of the cures are worse than the disease.

[http://www.amazon.com/Analyzing-Multivariate-Data-Norman-Cliff/dp/0155027042/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1446759842&sr=8-1&keywords=norman+cliff+multivariate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0155027042)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the book suggestion. I'll be sure to keep these in mind as I proceed.